# gather actually used C++ code lines

Tags: c++, g++, stripping

Is there a possibility (most likely by using gcc / g++ itself?) to determine which code lines of all files included by a single compilation are actually used?

I use much third-party includes and would like to strip them to the actually used code to speed up compilation.

Maybe g++ can output this by some combination of it's many options?

Comment: Can you use some of the third-party code as shared libraries and dynamically link them, thus avoiding the include('s compile time) altogether?

Comment: There has been word of a tool based on `libclang` that promised this. Google "Chandler Carruth include tool". I believe he mentioned it as early as GN2012

Comment: Try to move every `include` you can from .h to .c/.cpp files. Not an answer, but the usual trick.

Comment: @peachykeen That's not how the C++ compilation model works. You _still_ include the same includes.

Comment: @DanielFrey That's runtime coverage, not "required declarations to compile". Seriously, I think the OP should look at Precompiled Headers, or else indeed employ PIMPL techniques, compilation firewalling and perhaps subproject builds.

Comment: @sehe You include the same headers, yes, but you don't have to compile any of the bodies for them. If he's currently compiling third-party libs each time, perhaps because of the project or makefile, that's a super easy time saver. Headers are fairly cheap, and unless they are full of templates, stripping them isn't likely to help compile time much. Getting cpp files out of the way is going to be much better (and hopefully he's not including any cpp files).

Comment: @peachykeen "Headers are fairly cheap" [_needs citation_] Tell that to my compiler taking >20s to compile a 5 line program using a single boost header.

Comment: 'headers are fairly cheap' may hold. I just checked out precompiled headers, and had only very lousy benefits from them. Maybe 'precompilation of headers' does not do as much as one may expect, but I think it is the compilation and optimisation itself, not the preprocessing that takes most of the time I encountered, despite the fact I include masses of headers only very few functions are used from (eg. much of STL, OpenGL, glm which is a large eader-only math library and so on).

Comment: One problem with precompiled headers is that if one header is changed, the precompiled mega header must change.  Because the mega header changed, too many modules will need to change.  I believe precompiled headers are more of a hassle than the time they save.

Comment: But g++ allows to precompile every header individually, or not?

Comment: @sehe: "Headers are fairly cheap, **and unless they are full of templates**..." rules out Boost right away. ;)

Comment: As recent tests show most of my compilation time does not come from headers, for example `g++` exits after a few seconds on a coding mistake, where it already has resolved all includes, while taking 20 seconds to complete the compilation if all is right. So I like to unask the question...

Answer (score 1):

The best advice I can offer is to break apart huge include files into smaller pieces.  This allows developers to include only the files they need to resolve symbols.

My favorite example is `windows.h`.  The mega include file declares the entire Windows API, whether you need them or not.  If you only want the APIs for processing files, you get the APIs for dialg boxes as well.

Some shops like the monster include files because they only have to include the one file in their sources.  One draw back is that every source file now depends on mega include file.  If I change one of the include files, the entire system will be rebuilt instead of a few modules that depend on the header file that I changed.

In my projects, only a couple of files are compiled at a time; usually less than 5.  This makes the average turnaround time (modify then build) very fast.  The entire system is rebuilt overnight by a server or by developers.  There is no need to rebuild source files that have not changed.

So split up your modules, so you are not rebuilding your system every time.

Comment: I loosely remember mshtml.h, a >1mb of declaration hell... if headers should be a kind of documentation too, then MS HTML where made to be never understood...